# Drawing a Cube Using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, technical-drawing

I'm trying to simply use the example of a cube provided here

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
back line/.style={densely dotted},
cross line/.style={preaction={draw=white, -,
line width=6pt}}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
row sep=3em, column sep=3em,
text height=1.5ex,
text depth=0.25ex]{
& f^\ast E_V & & E_V \\
f^\ast E & & E \\
& U & & V \\
M & & N \\
};
\path[->]
(m-1-2) edge (m-1-4)
edge (m-2-1)
edge [back line] (m-3-2)
(m-1-4) edge (m-3-4)
edge (m-2-3)
(m-2-1) edge [cross line] (m-2-3)
edge (m-4-1)
(m-3-2) edge [back line] (m-3-4)
edge [back line] (m-4-1)
(m-4-1) edge (m-4-3)
(m-3-4) edge (m-4-3)
(m-2-3) edge [cross line] (m-4-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(originally from [here](http://www.felixl.de/commu.pdf)).

I can't seem to get it to work for whatever reason. It's throwing an error about

```
l.382 text depth=0.25ex]
```

For some reason. Anybody have any insight into this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you including  `\usetikzlibrary{matrix}`?  Instead of code snippets, it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Can you add your packages etc. to the code above? If you make it a minimal working example then we'll have better information to help you.

Comment: Oops. Weird when that happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply including `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usetikzlibrary{matrix}` in the preamble, and wrapping your code within the LaTeX wrapper seems to work fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
    % The tikz code goes here
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}%         Added to code
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}%   Added to code
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
back line/.style={densely dotted},
cross line/.style={preaction={draw=white, -,
line width=6pt}}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
row sep=3em, column sep=3em,
text height=1.5ex,
text depth=0.25ex]{
& f^\ast E_V & & E_V \\
f^\ast E & & E \\
& U & & V \\
M & & N \\
};
\path[->]
(m-1-2) edge (m-1-4)
edge (m-2-1)
edge [back line] (m-3-2)
(m-1-4) edge (m-3-4)
edge (m-2-3)
(m-2-1) edge [cross line] (m-2-3)
edge (m-4-1)
(m-3-2) edge [back line] (m-3-4)
edge [back line] (m-4-1)
(m-4-1) edge (m-4-3)
(m-3-4) edge (m-4-3)
(m-2-3) edge [cross line] (m-4-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That \usetikzlibrary{matrix} was the kicker. Thanks Peter.

Comment: That's why I try to insist that people not post code snippets and include the `\documentclass` and all the packages they are using as then it would have been more obvious.