# How to make a cube in latex

Tags: diagrams

I have to make a cube as shown in picture in latex. Kindly does any one know a simplest way of making cube please.
I would really appreciate.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: First: select package for drawing in LaTeX (TikZ, PStrick, ...), than browse for similar drawing in internet. For example, for TikZ see http://www.texample.net/. It has many different examples.

Comment: Asymptote is best for 3D in general - but has a steep learning curve.  Here's [one I did earlier](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295396/how-to-draw-this-also-how-to-put-dimension-on-that-outer-square-cube-its-side/295449#295449).

Comment: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/

Comment: Just some options around here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205442/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35317/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283729/1952

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Copy a picture of a cube and use \ingludegraphcs.

Comment: `\addplot3` in the `TikZ` package is your friend here. Simple, easy, and straightforward.